# Set Redux State in handleSubmit method of Formik React form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

I want to set a variable in the redux store that is gotten via Ajax after submitting a Formik react form

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from 'formik';

const LoginForm = ({
    values
  }) => {

  return (
        <div>
            <Form className={styles.LoginForm}>
              <Field className={input_classes} type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
              <Field className={input_classes} type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
              <button>Submit</button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setData: (data) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.ADD_DATA, data: data})
  }
}

const loginForm = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);

const FormikLoginForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues({ username, password }) {
    return {
      username: username || '',
      password: password || '',
    }
  },
  handleSubmit(values, props) {
    //make AJAX call and set data in redux store
  }
})(loginForm);

export default FormikLoginForm;
```

I cannot find a way to set any data to the store in the handleSubmit method; that is, how do I get access to the setData method that is returned mapDispatchToProps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order of HOC's matter, especially in this case (access to prop in another HOC) - redux `connect` must be outer to `withFormik`.

```
const FormikLoginForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues({ username, password }) {
    return {
      username: username || '',
      password: password || '',
    }
  },
  handleSubmit(values, { props } ) {
    //make AJAX call and set data in redux store
    props.setData( result )
  }
})(LoginForm);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FormikLoginForm);
```

Comment: thanks but there is no `setData` function attached to `props`.

Comment: second `handleSubmit` argument is an                  object - updated

Comment: thanks again, but still doesn't seem to be attached however I found that I can add to the store by using redux directly: `store.dispatch({type: "ADD_DATA", data: result})`

Comment: `console.log(props)` in `handleSubmit` ? inspect props with react dev tools? ... probably you can `handleSubmit(values, { props, setData } )` and use `setData` directly

Comment: I missed the point of your answer at first -- the fact that I was passing the wrong component to connect. Now it works. Thanks much.